# How to generate sonar test coverage for Angular project in subdirectory?

Tags: angular, maven, sonarqube, karma-jasmine

my Angular project structure is as follows and my code is inside subdirectory. below is my structure looks like

```
MyAngularProject
|
|--mycode
    |
    |--src
    |   |
    |   |-app
        |-assets
    |   |-main.ts
    |   |-test.ts
    |   
    |--angular.json
    |--karma.conf.ci.js
    |--karma.conf.js
    |--package.json
    |--tsconfig.json
```

below is karma.conf.js looks like

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      jasmine: {
       
      }
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage'),
      subdir: '.',
      reporters: [
        { type: 'html' },
        { type: 'lcovonly' },
        { type: 'text-summary' }
      ]
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```

karma.conf.ci.js

```
......
ciConfig.sonarQubeUnitReporter={
outputFile:'myreport.xml',
basePath:'src/app',
testFilePattern:'.spec.ts',
testPaths:['src']
}
```

package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test --code-coverage --karmaConfig=karma.conf.ci.js",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  }
```

pom.xml

```
....

  <properties>
    <sonar.host.url>http://localhost:9000</sonar.host.url>
    <sonar.language>ts</sonar.language>
    <sonar.sources>src</sonar.sources>
    <sonar.tests>src</sonar.tests>
    <sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths>coverage/report/lcov.info</sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths>
    <sonar.test.inclusions>**/*.spec.ts</sonar.test.inclusions>
    <sonar.coverage.exclusions>**/*.spec.ts</sonar.coverage.exclusions>
    <sonar.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sonar.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
   

      <!-- SonarQube Scanner -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0.2131</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>sonar</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <!-- Karma for unit tests -->
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>ng-test</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <executable>npm</executable>
                  <arguments>
                    <argument>test</argument>
                  </arguments>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Add your dependencies here -->
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

When i try to run 'mvn clean install', i can see coverage folder getting generated with lcov.info but
i am getting below error message after code coverage summary:

test:`ng test --watch=false --code-coverage`
Exit status 1
This is probably not a problem with npm.There is likely additional logging output above.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error:1

And when i run directly below cmd :
ng test --watch=false --code-coverage
It works as expected not sure whats wrong with pom.xml or other config.
can someone please help i am stuck at this from last 2-3 days.